# Radius of convergence of a particular power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of the power series f(x) = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\log n)x^n$ ?

I want to use root test. So basically how do I find $\lim (\log n)^{1/n}$ ?

Comment: Do you know that for example $\lim_{n\to\infty} k^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=1$ for constant $k\in\mathbb{R}_{\gt0}$?

Comment: If $a>1$ is a constant, then $a^n$ exceeds $n$ for large values of $n$. Hence also $a^n>\log n>1$ for large $n$. Therefore the limit is $1$. Mind you, the ratio test might be simpler, but suit yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is radius = 1  right?

Comment: Recall that the root (and ratio) tests are inconclusive when the limit is $1$...

Comment: The radius of convergence is the largest $r > 0$ such that $\log (n )c^n\to 0$ when $c < r$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the radius of convergence be $\rho$, then  $\dfrac{1}{\rho}=lim_{k\to\infty} sup\sqrt[n]{log(n)}$

$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge N, \sqrt[n]{log(n)}\lt L+\varepsilon; \forall n\ge N, \exists m\ge n$ such that $\sqrt[m]{log(m)}\gt L- \varepsilon$

Given any $\varepsilon \in (0,1), \forall n\ge 3 , n\lt 1+n\varepsilon\lt (1+\varepsilon)^n $. Hence, $\sqrt[n]{log(n)}\le \sqrt[n]{n}\lt 1+\varepsilon$. On the other hand, $ 1-\varepsilon\lt 1\lt \sqrt[n]{1}=1.$ Therefore, $\rho =1$.

If $x=1,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\log n)x^n= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\log n)$ diverges since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}log(k)=log(n!)$ is increasing and unbounded. If $x=-1, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\log n)x^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\log n)(-1)^n$. As $n\to \infty,(\log n)(-1)^n$ oscillates on $(-\infty, \infty)$. Therefore, the series diverges when $x=-1$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}=0.$$